# Drupal db_insert is not saving more than 440 records at a time

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am working on the Drupal CMS, where i am parsing a file & storing the data in DB.

So if there are more than 440 records (rows) in the file, it does not save it further. It works for the rows less than 440. It is an strange issue.

```
          $query = db_insert('table_name')->fields(array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));

          $row = 1;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {
                    $num = count($data);

                    if ($row > 1) {

                        $query->values(
                            array(
                                'fields1' => $data[0],
                                'fields2' => $data[2],
                                'fields3' => $data[4] 
                            )); 

                        if($row == '440'){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $row++;
                }


                $query->execute();
```

/////
 if($row == '440'){
                            break;
                        }

Is added to check how many rows it saves.. If i increase the 440 to 460, it doesn't save records to DB.

Comment: I have added the break statement to check whether it saves the 440 records or not. It work fine for 440, but if the file has 600 rows, it doesn't save single row too.

Comment: That test doesn't make sense. By adding it you GUARANTEE you won't write more than 440 rows. I mean... what happens if you set it to 441? Based on what you are saying only 440 rows get written. You don't need an if/break to show you that UNLESS you are getting an error of some sort on record 441 and you want to prevent that from happening. If you are getting an error you should really include the details of the error in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($row == '440'){
  break;
}
```

Remove this block and it'll be just fine.

Comment: That was a test if :: My txt file has 1000 rows, and it works for 440 records only. That if statement is only for the check how many rows it saves to db, so if i increase the 440 to 460 it doesn't save anything to db

Comment: That statement isn't a check of any sort, it stops the while loop after the 440th row.

Comment: I know that, thats i am saying if i remove this statement, no row get saved. That code is added to check how many rows it allows me to save, from this code i got i can save only 440 rows, not more than that.

Comment: Check [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) in MySQL, then, and the Drupal logs for any database errors it's throwing.

Comment: max_allowed_packet is 1 GB & there is no error in Drupal log... This is very strange issue. If i try to do it by normal PHP script & insert 10000 rows to table it works perfectly fine, but when i use the drupal db_query->execute(); it doesn't work :(

Comment: Why don't you batch them into groups of 100 at a time or something?

Comment: That is my last option, i was thinking to do that, but this will not be the proper solution for the problem, i am trying to get the solution.

Comment: You're going to need to debug further, then. Keep an eye on the queries in MySQL's `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, time the failures, etc.